# External Dependency Using cloud foundry CLI not working

Tags: cloud, cloud-foundry

I am trying to write a script to create external dependency service on cloud foundry, the script executes successfully but it not displaying IPs on web panel. Even when i bind the service with app it not allowing the listed IPs also. But if i configure external dependency from web panel then i am able to view all the entries of IPs and it allow the listed IPs. 
If anyone has used CLI to create external-dependency service with list of IPs suggest point out the issue on my implementation.

```
cf create-service external-dependency-service unstructured myservice -c dependency.json >> G:\Logs
```

dependency.json

```
{
"dependencyAsJson" : {
    "description" : "Testing External Dependency",
    "destinations" : [
    {
        "address" : "192.168.1.1",
        "protocol" : "tcp",
        "portStart" : 1,
        "portEnd" :  100
    },
    {
        "address" : "192.168.1.2",
        "protocol" : "tcp",
        "portStart" : 1,
        "portEnd" :  100
    }
    ]
}
}
```

You can see the logs to verify successful execution of cli command. Enable tracing using following command

```
cf config --trace=true
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The format of the json object must be in a specific format with escape string, in single line without line break and spaces between double quotes

```
cf create-service external-dependency-service unstructured myservice -c dependency.json >> G:\Logs

{"dependencyAsJson" : {\"description\" : \"Testing External Dependency\",\"destinations\" : [{\"address\" : \"192.168.1.1\",\"protocol\" : \"tcp\",\"portStart\" : 1,\"portEnd\" :  100},{\"address\" : \"192.168.1.2\",\"protocol\":\"tcp\",\"portStart\" : 1,\"portEnd\" : 100}]}}
```

if you are using it to inside the java string then you should \\ to maintain the format

```
{"dependencyAsJson" : {\\\"description\\\" : \\\"Testing External Dependency\\\",\\\"destinations\\\" : [{\\\"address\\\" : \\\"192.168.1.1\\\",\\\"protocol\\\" : \\\"tcp\\\",\\\"portStart\\\" : 1,\\\"portEnd\\\" :  100},{\\\"address\\\" : \\\"192.168.1.2\\\",\\\"protocol\\\":\\\"tcp\\\",\\\"portStart\\\" : 1,\\\"portEnd\\\" : 100}]}}
```

Comment: If I want to use it in json format, how to do that? Single line without line break is not readable and causes lot of typo errors. Can you provide some input on this?

Comment: @MrKumar I wrote application that maintains all the configuration into database so that same configuration can be pushed multiple PCF space with single button click. And also the same app would print the parsed json with my custom value so that i can copy it and use it in the commands. I will send you the sample code if i can find in my machine.

Comment: That would be great if you could provide your solution @Dipen